# How can I retrieve a list of table names and arrange them in ascending order based on their dates?

Tags: sas

I have some rows like this

```
BRANCH_AQB_INDIA_NOV2022_MAIN
BRANCH_AQB_INDIA_FEB2023_MAIN
BRANCH_AQB_INDIA_SEP2023_MAIN
BRANCH_AQB_INDIA_AUG2022_MAIN
BRANCH_AQB_INDIA_APR2023_MAIN
BRANCH_AQB_INDIA_JAN2024_MAIN
```

i want to sort them by asc like this

```
BRANCH_AQB_INDIA_AUG2022_MAIN
BRANCH_AQB_INDIA_NOV2022_MAIN
BRANCH_AQB_INDIA_FEB2023_MAIN
BRANCH_AQB_INDIA_APR2023_MAIN
BRANCH_AQB_INDIA_SEP2023_MAIN
BRANCH_AQB_INDIA_JAN2024_MAIN
```

Currently I'm just getting all the list with asc order like this in SAS

```
`
proc sql;
    select memname
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname = 'KALP51' and memname like 'BRANCH_AQB_INDIA_%_MAIN'
    order by memname asc;
quit;`
```

Comment: Every RDBMS is different. Stick to finding the solution in one and then, if you need to, translate from one dialect to another. If you get stuck doing that, then ask a *new* question about that.

Comment: sorry for that , i have now want only sas tag , i have added only sas tag here , i hope its correct

Comment: Note if the names were constructed using YMD digits, like 2022_08, then normal lexigraphic sorting would match chronological sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the date string from `memname`, convert it to a SAS date, and order by that value. You can do this with `scan` to get the second-to-last date string in `MONYY7.` format, then use `input` to convert it to a SAS date. Use the `outobs=1` option to only get the first row in the list.

```
proc sql outobs=1;
    select memname
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname = 'KALP51' and memname like 'BRANCH_AQB_INDIA_%_MAIN'
    order by input(scan(memname, -2, '_'), monyy7.);
quit;`
```

```
memname
BRANCH_AQB_INDIA_AUG2022_MAIN
```

Comment: thanks a lot , just one last thing , how can i get just the top 1 row of the list, i will accept the ans in 1 min as shown to me

Comment: Updated the answer for this